# How to tell Webpack not to pack a config file

Tags: webpack

I am using Webpack for an Angular 4/TypeScript project and in one of my modules, I want to access a `config.json` file with some values that must be configurable on the server (i.e., config values that can be changed at runtime instead of being fixed at compile time).

In my source, I refer to that file using

```
let config = require('./../relative/path/config.json');
```

It works nicely but webpack packs it up and in the resulting `dist` the values of the config file end up along with the rest in the `app.XXX.js` file.

I tried to mark the file in `webpack.common.js` (which is referenced by the other webpack configuration files) by adding it to the `externals`, but that doesn't change anything. I had hoped that webpack would then simply not pack up the file but deploy it as-is to the `dist` directory.

**Question:** can I have my `config.json`, and have webpack *not* pack it but simply deploy it, so that I can modify or replace the file upon deployment instead of opening `app.XXX.js` and searching for the values?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Could you just load your config.json file in webpack and define it's value in your bundle with the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) ?

Comment: The idea is to change configuration values at runtime, not compile time...

Answer (score 1):

First thing to realize is that your webpack'ed application is not running on the server, but in the client's browser. Although this `require` call looks like a call to read a file at runtime, it is in fact just an instruction to webpack to bundle a file and deliver it to browser embedded in the bundle. The bundle itself is served as plain file to the browser.

In light of this, simple task of *reading a configuration file at runtime* becomes: *fetching a file from the server and parsing it at runtime*. Fortunately webpack has dedicated infrastructure to do exactly this: [import()](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-).

```
import('./../relative/path/config.json').then(config => {
  // Do something with 'config'
})
```

or if you are still on legacy JavaScript, you can use legacy [require.ensure()](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-ensure).

```
require.ensure(['./../relative/path/config.json'], function(require) {
  let config = require('./../relative/path/config.json');
  // Do something special...
});
```